# Bootstrap CSS - Thumbnail Image Resize & Responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an ecommerce app in Rails and using Bootstrap's thumbnail class to display product listings in category pages and widgets.

My images are of different sizes. I want to fix the thumbnail container to some height and width (responsive) and then resize the images to be the **largest possible scaled version** within the constrained height and width of the thumbnail container.

And the caption/price should be aligned accordingly.

here is a demo. scroll down. http://mktdemo.herokuapp.com/

I am looking for some css I can include on the thumbnail class to set this.

My html (with some ruby):

```
  <div class="row">
     <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="thumbnail" >
          <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url, class: "img-responsive"), listing %>
          <div class="caption">
             <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
             <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

I've tried the below but this only fixes the container size, not the image or the caption alignment. And since I'm fixing the height and width, it's likely not responsive either.

```
.thumbnail {
   width: 260px;
   height: 300px;
  }
```

Comment: it's col-** who set width to thumbnail already

Comment: Are you trying to compensate for that tall listing? One way to go about adjusting it would be to set a max-height on the `.thumbnail a` to crop the `<img>`, set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: @AlexDom Ok, yes, I didn't think of that. So I'd need css for the col classes. I want them to be responsive but scaled within a certain width and height.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/steLu15r/ ?

Comment: @Evan no, in the fiddle the images are not scaled to fit. The first 2 images are incomplete.

Comment: It looks like only the second of the new additions is being cropped. You'd rather have it scaled to `height: 100%;` and appear squashed? Here it is with the dimensions you provided above. http://jsfiddle.net/bmxfum7r/

Comment: for col you have classes like (lg,md,sm,xs)-x(where x is 1-12), explained here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options. They give a width to col for a special container width

Comment: @Evan now there is blank space below smaller images. I want each image to be the **largest scaled image** within the constrained space.

Comment: Do all images have same proportions or is there a mix of portrait and landscape images?

Comment: @Salman_A all different sizes and proportions. It's a marketplace app so sellers will load images. That's why I want to resize on my end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating divs for your gallery and use css to set the image as a background image. Then, use the property `background-size`. You can either use `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`.  Setting the background-size: cover will scale the image so that it completely fills the background area while cutting off the excess. Setting background-size: contain will scale the image so that it maintains its original aspect ratio and fills the background without cutting off the image.

so your code must be looking something like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail img-responsive">
  <div class="cell" id="image1"></div>
    ......
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#image1{
  background: url("path");
  background-size:cover;
}

.thumbnail{
   width:250px;
   height:250px;
}
```

hope this helps :)
good luck!

Comment: That works for background but not practical to do this for product images. I'd have to put ruby code in the css.

Comment: Is there a 'contain' option that I can use within my html? Something in the <img> tag which will scale withing the container but keep the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question. Just got notified that I got a badge because this question was viewed 1000+ times.

I had to set some settings within Imagemagick while loading the image. My site uses rails/paperclip but as long as you're using imagemagick, these settings below should work.

I figured this out and posted the answer here - [Rails 4 - Imagemagick Resize to fill space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649334/rails-4-imagemagick-resize-to-fill-space/25658477#25658477)